# When does the garbage collector collect instances created with AppDomain.CreateInstance?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, appdomain

In my application I create a new AppDomain.  I then create an instance of a type that inherits from MarshalByRefObject in the AppDomain using CreateInstanceAndUnwrap and assign it to a variable in the default AppDomain.  For the sake of the example, I'll call the object "ObjectA".

Correct me if I'm wrong, but if I remove all references to ObjectA in the default AppDomain and the child AppDomain, I'd expect the garbage collector to collect ObjectA.  However if ObjectA is created and it spins up a Thread or long-running Task that never exits, I wouldn't expect the garbage collector to collect it.

Is there any way to tell the garbage collector to collect an object in a different AppDomain?  Or am I forced to unload the AppDomain?

Answer (score 1):

If you are running a thread that has a reference to the object then you have left one reference to that object in the appdomain, until the thread exits you won't have it collected.

My suggestion would be to make the object implement `IDisposable` and have it cancel the long running task/thread when it is called.

Comment: How likely is it that disposed objects are garbage collected?  What if the task/thread continues to run after the object is supposed to be disposed?  (all bad practices, obviously, but in the case of a plugin architecture you can't be sure)

Comment: Really you should be reading up on this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088(v=vs.110).aspx If it's a plugin that you are sandboxing is there really a problem with killing the appdomain that you have used to host it? If it's not your code then obviously you can't control them misbehaving but you can provide a way for the plugin to be notified that it is being unloaded before nuking it's sandbox.

Comment: The short answer about GC of disposed ojects is that it doesn't change anything. The reason you provide a disposable interface  is simply to notify the object that it's owner is done with it and it's time to clean up it's unmanaged resources, it does not notify the GC about collecting it. That will happen based on whether it is currently referenced by an object that hasn't been collected yet.